# Wordpress not working on CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, wordpress, centos

I am trying to set up `WordPress` on  `CentOS 6.2`. I am able to  set up everything including `MySQL`, PHP and `WordPress`.

This is entry in my `httpd.config` file under `/etc/httpd/config`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin xxx@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName travellingrants
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/travellingrants-error-log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/travellingrants-acces-log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Though home page is loading, but when i click on any other link say `http://ip/travellingrants/himachal-pradesh`, i am getting 404 error

```
The requested URL /travellingrants/himachal-pradesh was not found on this server.
```

This is what i have in error log file

```
[Tue Nov 12 04:36:31 2013] [error] [client XXXX] File does not exist: /var/www/html/travellingrants/himachal-pradesh, referer: http://server-ip/travellingrants/
```

I have created placed WordPress flies under travellingrants directory under `/var/www/html`.Not sure why this is happening as my knowledge with Linux is limited.

I tried `>setstatus` and got this result

```
[root@li635-245 ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you check your .htaccess file.

The problem might be because you develop the site locally under different folder name.

Here is the sample of Wordpress .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /some-folder
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /some-folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

PS: change **some-folder** into **travellingrants**

Comment: well, i developed site with same folder name, anyways will try to follow your way

Comment: seems like this solution is not working.I am not sure why it is happening but it says in is unable to find file for requested URL

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the folder in the **html** directory but the browser can't it is a permission option. Apache needs to have access to the files so that it can serve them up to the client (browser).

Try this. 
**sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/travellingrant**

Note: that you need to access your directory via FTP you will need **chown**(change ownership) back to the FTP user.

Comment: Rudy Lee could be right as well. There are really a number of reasons why this could happen.

Comment: I tested this option also but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reload apache?
sudo service httpd reload

may as well restart it also

sudo service httpd reload